# Install SQL Server Express 2008 in Silent mode along with a C# application

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, windows-installer

I need to install SQL Server 2008 Express along with my C# application, but in a silent mode.
As I want it to be easy for the user (who is a very basic user), I guess I will need a configuration file in order to specify all the parameters that I want it to be installed with.

Can this configuration file be packaged with Visual Studio 2008 so everything is generated, or should I just create the config file, put it into the CD and when SQL Server is installing, specify the config file to be installed with?

Cheers everybody in advance!

Comment: Would Sql-Server Compact be a viable option for you? Would be much easier

Comment: @BrokenGlass Yes, I think so, but then I would have to change the bootstrapper I have for Visual Studio 2008

Comment: It would probably be easier for you to move the SQL-CE than get an unattended SQL express install to work... in all cases. (what if they already have sql express installed, for example)

Comment: @AndrewBarber so, I should create a new bootstrapper for SQL-CE and install it then, as it's the easiest option?

Comment: No; you don't install SQL-CE; you reference the library for it in your project. That's the point: it's not a separate install at all.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I don't think that can be an option then :(

Comment: Your installer shouldn't even bat an eye at it; the VS install project does it by default. But, OK.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to set some sort of custom action for this project?

Answer (score 3):

It can be done. You need to make your EXE bootstrapper launch the SQL Server prerequisite with a custom command line which contains a configuration file or the appropriate command line parameters for a silent install.

Visual Studio setup projects do not support custom prerequisite creation. However, it can be done by manually generating the required manifests.

You can find the manifests structure here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229223(VS.80).aspx

These manifests can be generated automatically with the [Bootstrapper Manifest Generator](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/bmg) tool.

After generating the package manifests, you can add all these files (including the package) in a separate folder in the Visual Studio prerequisites folder, for example:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages
```

You can then select the custom prerequisite in your setup project Properties page.

Comment: A ClickOnce installer was previously generated by someone else and it didn't work, as we were having problems with installing the application as administrator and then an ordinary user not being able to execute it due to permission conflicts. Is this possible to be done as a normal setup/deployment project?

Comment: The instructions in my post are for a setup project. You can't do it with ClickOnce.

Comment: nevertheless, that bootstrapper tool is really buggy, as I can't get it properly running under Windows 7 x64 - I only get exceptions

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this personally but there are short clear instructions [here](http://sqlbeyond.blogspot.com/2011/07/sql-server-express-2008-r2-unattended.html)

http://sqlbeyond.blogspot.com/2011/07/sql-server-express-2008-r2-unattended.html

Basically, extract your files to a folder and invoke installation as follows:

```
SETUP.exe /ACTION=Install /INSTANCENAME=SQLExpress /FEATURES=SQLENGINE /QS /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS=true /SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" /BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Disabled /ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN=true /TCPENABLED=1 /HIDECONSOLE
```

Comment: yes but what I actually want, is my Visual Studio deployment project to generate the setup.exe with those commands, is it possible?

Comment: Possible... but  what do you do on a client system that already has sql express installed, or has a restrictive firewall that prevents the tcp pipe from working, or has something using the tcp port you expect to use...

Comment: Well, if they already have install, can't they cancel the installation of SQL Server and let my application be installed?

Comment: @noloman No... if you are installing "unattended", you would end up with potentially a second instance, or incomprehensible installation errors... things you say you specifically want to avoid.

Comment: @AndrewBarber well now I have setup the `package.xml` and added SQL Express 2008 as a prerequisite for my setup project. I have lines such as `<Command PackageFile="SQLEXPR32_x86_ENU.EXE" Arguments='/q /hideconsole /action=Install /features=SQL /instancename=SQLEXPRESS /enableranu=1 /sqlsvcaccount="NT Authority\Network Service" /AddCurrentUserAsSqlAdmin /skiprules=RebootRequiredCheck' EstimatedInstalledBytes="225000000" EstimatedInstallSeconds="420">` but still, I get the full console visible to the user, which is not what I want.. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to install quiet silence from c# the code is this:
Care to take away all spaces in the string argumentos, I don´t know why but they go with the string and doesn´t work properly

```
        String sqlfile = @"\Msi\SQLEXPR_x64_ESN.exe"; 
        //or wathever sql inst file you have
        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = sqlfile;            
        String argumentos = @"/qs /Action=Install  /Features=SQL,Tools /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS=""True"" /INSTANCENAME=""SQLExpress_AV"" /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=""Builtin\Administrators"" /SQLSVCACCOUNT=""NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"" ";

        //MessageBox.Show(argumentos);
        myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = argumentos;
        myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        myProcess.Start();
```