# How to Install Sql server based software?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

Guys I have made a medical mangment system in c# using windows form application on visual studio and SQL Server.
Now i want to install it on other desktop.
How can i do this ? I want to give him a only .exe file and installing it it should work as it works now own my Laptop.

Comment: I assume you mean SQL Express? Otherwise this is a licensing violation.

Comment: Yes. SQL Express that is free to download.

Comment: Do you mean the application or the SQL server instance?

Comment: application, that i have made on visual Studio.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Install SQL Server Express 2008 in Silent mode along with a C# application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8011240/install-sql-server-express-2008-in-silent-mode-along-with-a-c-sharp-application)

Comment: No My question is different.

Comment: Do you want to connect to the same SQL instance or install a separate instance on the new machine?

Comment: How is your question different? How do you currently install it on your laptop?

Comment: You question is not different (at least not as presently described). If it is different please explain how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bundling SQL express into an existing application is a complex process, not easily described in one post.  I would suggest starting with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd981032(v=sql.100).aspx, then make a new question for any challenges you encounter.

Comment: Doing it this way can get very ugly and there are 1 million things that can go wrong. Not a great idea.